# How to show entire field value without scientific notation?

Tags: html, jsp

There is a field :

```
<div id="div_montant_src_financement" class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pr&eacute;vu</label>
    <form:input path="prevu" cssClass="form-control input_text numeric" placeholder="Budget prévu" />
</div>
```

css :

```
.form-control {
    border-color: #729aea !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #0a0aaf !important;
}
.form-control:not(textarea):not([multiple]) {
    height: 28px !important;
}
.input_text {
    width: 66.66666667% !important;
}
```

jquery :

```
$('.numeric').on("keyup",function () {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    }
});

$('.numeric').css("text-align","right");
```

At runtime the field is populated from column data in database ; it has a value 15000000 but the rendered data is not like I want :

[image]

So how to show all the value without the scientific notation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Image showing formatted value]

Did you try toFixed() method?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try this:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:formatNumber value="15000000" pattern="#.000"/>
```